# spuriously italicized footnote hooks in tex4ht output

Tags: footnotes, tex4ht, latex-to-word

`tex4ht` spuriously italicizes footnote hooks (e.g., "1" for the first footnote) at the bottom of the page when the first word of the footnote is italicized.

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{calc}

%Greek
\newcommand{\greek}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\gk}[1]{#1}

%Arabic
\newcommand{\ar}[1]{#1}
\newenvironment{arab}{}{}

% Bibliography etc
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\usepackage{textcomp} % For angle brackets `\textlangle` and `\textrangle`

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    My text goes here:    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Text.\footnote{Ordinary footnote: \cite{knuth:ct}.}

Text.\footnote{\emph{Italicized} first word of footnote.}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    My text ends here:    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix this bug?

Comment: Something similar happens when the first word of a footnote is in **boldface**: the footnote hook becomes boldface too.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with current version of ooffice configuration, maybe it had been fixed as a consequence of another fix?

Comment: You're right -- it has been fixed in the new version! Thank you for pointing that out. Perhaps that should become the official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was seemingly fixed by recent `tex4ht` development, as the current development version produces the following result (the page had been resized to make the screenshot smaller):

[image]